# How to use source model reuse in custom module custom field Email Sender in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: adminhtml, email-templates, magento2.3.1

How to use source model reuse in custom module custom field Email Sender in Magento 2.3.1

> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity

Our custom module custom field like this

```
 $fieldset->addField(
        'email_sender',
        'select',
        ['name' => 'email_sender', 'label' => __('Email Sender'), 'title' => __('Email Sender'), 'required' => true]
    );
```